# Condition to sum of geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series

In high school we all learned that $\sum{x^n}=(1-x)^{-1}$ iff $|x|<1$.

My question: what if $x$ is not a real number, but something else, e.g. an operator? Does the equation still hold? What are the general criteria?

Comment: The same result holds when $x$ is a complex number. In that case, $|x|$ means the modulus of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this principle can be generalized in some conditions. Just like $(I-A)^{-1}=\sum A^n$ in $\rho(A)<1$ where $I$ is unit matrix, $A$ is a complex matrix and $\rho(A)$ is spectral radius of $A$. Personally, for an operator $T$, if a reasonable measure of $T$ is less than 1, say, $\|T\|<1$, the inverse of $I-T$ can be expanded as the form you give and it is convergence in the meaning of $\|(I-T)^{-1}-\sum T^n\|=0$. I remember a book about functional analysis have describe this problem but my memory is not clearly now. You can read some references about it. Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: The keyword is [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).